# Can I emulate a click of an element by html value of it?

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```
<ul>
    <li>Start</li>
    <li>Hello my</li>
    <li>name is</li>
    <li>Marco</li>    
</ul>
```

and I'd like to emulate che "click" of the `<li>` with html "Hello my", for example, without "cycle all items" and check the `.html()`.

So a sort of selector by html value. Is it exist in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) :

```
$("ul li:contains('Hello my')")
```

But it would take also elements like :

```
<li>woHello myrld</li>
```

It would be better to use a [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
$("ul li").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=="Hello my"; })
```

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
jQuery(':contains("Hello my")');
```

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a dropdown box:

```
<select>
 <option value="Start">Start</option>
 <option value="Hello my">Hello my</option>
 <option value="name is">name is</option>
 <option value="Marco">Marco</option>    
</select>
```

Then you can bind to the `.change` event using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").contains("Hello my").click();
```

Note that `click()` only fires a click event for jquery to detect - if doesn't replicate an actual "physical" click.